# Output Redirection in C shell

Tags: c, unix, shell, redirect

I asked about pipes in a previous question, got that working perfectly. However I had some questions about output redirection like >> in a shell normally does. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of info on the Internet about it. Here is what I have so far. Is there a better/easier way to do this, it's messy and im not even super sure that I understand it. Part of it was psuedocode given in notes, i kinda filled them in, but even im not super sure.

```
void do_redirect(char** cmd, char** file) {
  int fds[2]; 
  int count; 
  int fd;     
  char i;    
  pid_t pid;  
  pipe(fds);
  //File Descriptors/pipe and redirecting char variables (i)
  //fd is used with the open command, basically stores the 

  //Child 1
  if (fork() == 0) {
    //Open the file with read/write commands, 0_CREAT creates the file if it does not exist
    fd = open(file[0], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    dup2(fds[0], 0);

    //Close STDOUT
    close(fds[1]);

    //Read from STDOUT
    while ((count = read(0, &i, 1)) > 0)
    write(fd, &i, 1); // Write to file.

    exit(0);

  //Child 2
  } else if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    dup2(fds[1], 1);

    //Close STDIN
    close(fds[0]);

    //Output contents to the given file.
    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
    perror("execvp failed");

  Parent
  } else {
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What, precisely, do you want to know?

Comment: I basically meant to ask does this "look" correct. Also how come on read, i use a 0 instead of the actual "fd" descriptor, because I tried using fd instead of 0 (like the man pages said) and I got an executable text file with nothing in it...

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `O_APPEND` if it's `>>` you are looking for.

Comment: Ya thanks, I added it, although...if your not using 0_APPEND and u >> cat to a file that already exists, does it just replace it or put it at the beginning?

Comment: If you were trying to implement the shell, you'd add O_APPEND for >> and not for >.